# Compare two columns from same table and case on third column value using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Compare two columns from same table and if child value matches with preceding or succeeding or any parent value then case col3 value with parent value and col3 must not be null

Table:

| Child | Parent | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | null | 4 |
| b | a | null |
| c | b | null |

Expected:

| Child | Parent | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | null | 4 |
| b | a | 4 |
| c | b | 4 |

Here Child column  value "a" is matching with parent column value "a" so col3 changed to 4

Comment: Please show your attempt and explain what is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that throu cte and recursion. (if your recursion depth is more than 100 then add option (maxrecursion 0) or your desired recursion levelat the end of query)

Schema and insert statement:

```
 Create table mytable(Child varchar(10),Parent varchar(10), col3 int) ;
 Insert into mytable values('a',    null,      4) ;
 Insert into mytable values('b',    'a',    null) ;
 Insert into mytable values('c',    'b',    null) ;
```

Query:

```
 With cte as
 (
 Select *FROM mytable where parent is null 
 Union all
 Select m. child, m.parent, coalesce(m. col3, cte. Col3) from mytable m inner join cte on m.Parent=cte. Child
 
 )
 Select *from cte
```

Output:

| Child | Parent | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | *null* | 4 |
| b | a | 4 |
| c | b | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=30910e18f97ed4aeb171984381ecf6c2)*